# How to use passenger with RoR and supervisor and rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rbenv, supervisord

I am trying to use passenger with ror with supervisor.

This is the error I get:

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

But I am using rbenv with the bundler path here with ruby 2.1.5 not 1.9.1:

```
BUNDLER_HOME='/opt/rbenv/shims/bundler'
```

I even set in .bashrc and in supervisor.  Yet I get that error?

```
[program:passenger]

directory=/var/etl-rails
environment=RAILS_ENV="development", BUNDLER_HOME='/opt/rbenv/shims/bundler'
command = /usr/bin/passenger start
autostart=true
autorestart=true

stopsignal=KILL
stopasgroup = true
killasgroup = true

stdout_logfile=/tmp/passenger.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=100MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10

stderr_logfile = /tmp/passenger.err
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
```

So....supervisor is trying to use 1.9.1.  I can start passenger from the command line but I have to run the below:

```
rbenv global 2.1.5
/usr/bin/passenger start
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: supervisor, by default, runs as root. If you rbenv is configured under an specific user (the typical case), you should tell supervisor to run Rails under that user:

```
user = my_unix_username
```

You also need rbenv to be initialized (its initalization script is usually on an user's `~/.profile` or some other file). You can reproduce the configs on `environment=`, but I usually just run Rails within a `bash` in login (`-l) mode, which will initialize this user's context appropriately, that is:

```
command = bash -lc "/usr/bin/passenger start"
```